# How can I re-render(refresh) bottom tab bar in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

[image]    I am struggling with the
import { create Bottom Tab Navigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
I want re-render bottom tab after removing cart Items from cart component by dispatch action    and my focused tab is cart tab,
and i am also used a custom components for getting cart Count from state below i am sharing   the code of bottom tab icon.

```
 export class Cart Badge Icon extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  }
    render() {
     return (
        <>
            <Image source={this.props.is-focused ? IMP_CONT.CART_ACTIVE :
                MG_CONT.CART_INACTIVE} style={{ width: scale(25), height: scale(22) }} />
            {this.props.counterproductive ?
                (<View
                    >
                <Text>{this.props.cart Count}
                 </Text>
                </View>
                ) : null}
             </>
            )
          }
         }
    cont map State To Props = (state) => ({
     cart Has Product Flag: state.cart.cart Has Product,
     cart Count: state.cart.cart Count,
    })
   export default connect(map State To Props)(Cart Badge Icon)
   and i have import this component in my bottom Tab like this <Cart Badge Icon/>
```

Comment: you can use react context api https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: I am also using redux @Ahmed Gaber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after one day's i fond the solution,
i dispatch a action for receiving cartCount and i already get cartCout in   CartBadgeIcon component.